# Using notification in Android App

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

My application is going to install in various devices...i want to add a message from my side and it must be sent as a notification to every device on which my app is installed. 
How to do this??

Comment: Look this :[http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and official [Docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html)

Comment: try this [gcm](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) or [GCM Android](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: i wonder, you build your full application and yet you didn't heard of gcm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to do that. [Here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) you can find guidelines about this service.